# Undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘append’? build error

Tags: c

I was trying to compile this .c script for centos or ubuntu using gcc and after getting this error tried to debug with Code Blocks but couldn't get around this same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#ifdef LINUX
#include <getopt.h>
#endif

#define STRLEN 1024*64

#define FILE1 argv[optind]
#define FILE2 argv[optind+1]

#define TEMPFILE "temp.nmon"

void hint()
{
    (void)printf("Hint: convert an nmon file so it can be merged with an older one\n");
    (void)printf("Syntax: nmonmerge [-a] [-v] original-file extra-file\n");
    (void)printf("\t[-a] append converted extra-file data to end of the original-file\n");
    (void)printf("\t[-v] verbose extra details are output\n\n");
/*            12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 */
    (void)printf("Without -a the merged data is send to stdout, so redirect it (\">\") to\n");
    (void)printf("\tsave the converted data.\n");
    (void)printf("Note: that header lines are striped out of the 2nd file as they are already\n");
    (void)printf("\tin the original file. This assumes no configuration changes like new\n");
    (void)printf("\tdisks, LUNs, adapters, networks etc., which would cause header and\n");
    (void)printf("\tdata column mismatches\n");
    (void)printf("Note: only the timestamps (Tnnnn) and the number of snapshots are modified\n");
    (void)printf("\teverything else is unchanged.\n");
    (void)printf("Note: be careful as you might have \"missing\" snapshots in the time\n");
    (void)printf("\tbetween the data files.\n");
    (void)printf("Note: an extra line is added, starting \"AAA,note\" and the filename\n");
    (void)printf("\tthis line is ignored other tools but will help in diagnosing errors\n");
    (void)printf("Note: do NOT sort the nmon file before merging (sorting not needed now anyway)\n");
    (void)printf("Note: nmonmerge uses a temporary file called temp.nmon\n");
    (void)printf("Example: to merge three files a.nmon, b.nmon and c.nmon\n");
    (void)printf("\tnmonmerge -a a.nmon b.nmon\n");
    (void)printf("\tnmonmerge -a a.nmon c.nmon\n");
    (void)printf("\tNow a.nmon contains all the data\n");
    (void)printf("Example: to merge three files a.nmon, b.nmon and c.nmon\n");
    (void)printf("\tnmonmerge a.nmon b.nmon >x.nmon\n");
    (void)printf("\tnmonmerge x.nmon c.nmon >y.nmon\n");
    (void)printf("\trm x.nmon\n");
    (void)printf("\tNow y.nmon contains all the data\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    FILE *readfp;
    FILE *writefp;
    int i,j,k,hit,number;
    char string[STRLEN+1];

    int lastzzzz = 0;
    int verbose = 0;
    int append = 0;

    writefp = stdout;
    while ( -1 != (i = getopt(argc, argv, "?hva" ))) {
                switch (i) {
                case '?':
                case 'h':
            hint();
                case 'v':
            verbose++;
            break;
                case 'a':
            append++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(optind +2 != argc) {
        (void)printf("Error: this command expects two filenames (nmon collected data files)\n");
        hint();
    }
        if( (readfp = fopen(FILE1,"r")) == NULL){
                perror("failed to open original file for reading");
                (void)printf("file: \"%s\"\n",FILE1);
        exit(75);
        }
        if( (writefp = fopen(TEMPFILE,"w+")) == NULL){
                perror("failed to open temporary file for write");
                (void)printf("file: \"%s\"\n",TEMPFILE);
        exit(75);
        }

    (void)fprintf(writefp,"AAA,note,merged file %s starts here\n",FILE1);
    for(i=0;fgets(string,STRLEN,readfp)!= NULL;i++) {
        if(!strncmp(string, "ZZZZ,T",6)) {
            sscanf(&string[6],"%d",&lastzzzz);
        }
        fprintf(writefp,"%s",string);
    }
    if(verbose)(void)printf("First file has %d snapshots in %d lines\n", lastzzzz,i);
    fclose(readfp);

    if(lastzzzz == 0) {
        (void)printf("File %s does not include any ZZZZ lines! - this can't be an nmon output file = stopping.\n",FILE1);
        exit(33);
    }

        if( (readfp = fopen(FILE2,"r")) == NULL){
                perror("failed to open extra data file for reading");
                (void)printf("file: \"%s\"\n",FILE2);
        exit(75);
        }

    /* wind forward to first ZZZZ line to skip header lines */
    for(i=0;fgets(string,STRLEN,readfp)!= NULL;i++) {
        if(!strncmp(string, "ZZZZ,T",6)) {
            (void)fprintf(writefp,"AAA,note,merged file %s starts here\n",FILE2);
            (void)sscanf( &string[6],"%d",&number);
            (void)sprintf(&string[6],"%04d", lastzzzz + number);
            string[10] = ',';
            (void)fprintf(writefp,"%s",string);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(verbose)(void)printf("Skipped %d header lines in second file\n", i);

    for(k=0,hit=0;fgets(string,STRLEN,readfp)!= NULL;k++) {
        /* 3 for short MEM,Tnnnn  and 12 for TOP,1234567,Tnnn */
        for(j=3;j<12;j++) {
            if(string[j  ] == ',' &&
               string[j+1] == 'T' &&
               isdigit(string[j+2]) ) {
                hit++;
/*              if(verbose)(void)printf("was=%s",string); */
                (void)sscanf( &string[j+2],"%d",&number);
                (void)sprintf(&string[j+2],"%04d", lastzzzz + number);
                string[j+6] = ',';
                (void)fprintf(writefp,"%s",string);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(verbose)(void)printf("Out of %d lines, converted %d lines, last snapshot was %d\n", i+k,hit, lastzzzz+number);
    fclose(readfp);
    fclose(writefp);
        

    if(append) {
        if( (writefp = fopen(FILE1,"w")) == NULL){
            perror("failed to open original file writing");
            (void)printf("file: \"%s\"\n",FILE1);
            exit(75);
        }
        if(verbose)(void)printf("Output placed back in %s\n",FILE1);
    } else {
        writefp = stdout;
    }
    if( (readfp = fopen(TEMPFILE,"r")) == NULL){
        perror("failed to open temporary file for reading");
        (void)printf("file: \"%s\"\n",TEMPFILE);
        exit(75);
    }

    for(i=0;fgets(string,STRLEN,readfp)!= NULL;i++) {
        if(!strncmp(string, "AAA,snapshots,",14)) {
            fprintf(writefp,"AAA,snapshots,%d\n",lastzzzz+number);
        }
        else
            fprintf(writefp,"%s",string);
    }
    unlink(TEMPFILE);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is pointing to this line: `if(optind +2 != argc) {` and this script is to be used to merge nmon log files and was taken from here: http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php?n=Site.Nmonmerge

I have no prior C programming knowledge so not sure where to start, nor the error is descriptive enough to give me any clues.

Full error with warnings:

```
error: 'optind' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'append'?|
note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
warning: implicit declaration of function 'isdigit' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. And copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output (as text) into the question.

Comment: also, the error tells you pretty much exactly what's wrong: you're using an identifier that you've not declared.

Comment: why do you have all these `(void)` in front of your `printf`?

Comment: I'm guessing the header file isn't being included, which could mean your `LINUX` isn't defined, so the external variable [optind](https://linux.die.net/man/3/optind) isn't defined.

Comment: I think you need to `#include <unistd.h>`. Also, the `(void)`s in front of all your `printf`s, `scanf`s, etc., are completely unnecessary.

Comment: FYI, your haphazard identation makes your code very hard to read. Each open-brace should increase the indent by 4 spaces, and each close-brace should decrease it by 4. Using VIM will take care of this automatically.

Comment: For `printf` the `(void)` is unnecessary unless you are running the code through some MISRA checker. For `scanf` that cast is a no-go! You should check the return value of `scanf` and other IO functions. Ignoring them can hide many errors.

Comment: The identifier that is undefined should be printed right before the message you show us. That is actually the most important part of that message. Check what name is shown there, check where it is defined and make sure the corresponding header is included.

Comment: Change LINUX to `__linux__`

Comment: @SGeorgiades After adding the unistd.h I got 2 different outcomes in that by using gcc on centos I was able to compile the script with 2 warnings 1. implicit declaration of function ‘strncmp’ 2. implicit declaration of function ‘isdigit’ and using Code Blocks nothing changed. I can consider my issue solved but I would still love to be able to finish the build in CB

Comment: To fix the `strncmp` error, `#include <string.h>`, and to fix the `isdigit` error, `#include <ctype.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`optind` should be defined in `unistd.h`. Since you use `getopt()`, you need this variable to keep track of the parameter that is currently being processed.

> The variable optind is the index of the next element to be processed in argv. The system initializes this value to 1. The caller can reset it to 1 to restart scanning of the same argv, or when scanning a new argument vector.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/optind

Verify that required include files are being included. You are compiling on Linux, so you can simply remove `#ifdef LINUX` and the corresponding `#endif`.

You can also open `unistd.h` that comes with your compiler to see if it defines `optind`.